# I cannot understand why the border I've created isn't slicing up into the correct proportions (CSS)

Tags: css, border, slice, border-image

I've created a border in GIMP. The corner slices are 50px x 20px. However the result I get is very squished up and small.

This is my border

[image]

Here is the code I'm trying to add to a `500px x 100px` div:

```
border-left: 20px solid black;
border-right: 20px solid black;
border-image-source: url(http://i.imgur.com/1AUVP8x.png);
border-image-slice: 20 50;
border-image-repeat: round;
border-image-outset: 0px;
```

[liveweave](http://liveweave.com/3HftVX)

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what effect you were going for but this seems to work.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.lw {
  font-size: 40px;
}

div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 20px;
  background: pink;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px 50px 20px 50px;
  border-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/1AUVP8x.png) 20 50 repeat;
}

.tall {
  height:200px;
```

```html
<div>
<p class="lw">Hello Weaver!</p>
</div>

<div class="tall">
<p class="lw">Hello Weaver!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah I see, thank you very much. So the key difference is that I had normal `border-left`s and `border-right`s whereas I should have been using border-width? Much appreciate the help.